# Why does ` give me a syntax error

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to use a timer in javascript however a syntax error is occurring and I do not know why

```
var timer = setInterval(`changeLights()`,3000);
```

Comment: You are passing the function as a string, remove the quotation marks.

Comment: Did you mean to use ticks? Does the bowser support them?

Answer (score 5):

You're using backticks instead of regular quotes. Also, the first argument passed to `setTiemout`or `setInterval` *can* be a string, but it's bad form. You should be passing a function directly:

```
var timer = setInterval(changeLights,3000);
```

Functions, in JS, are first-class. That means they can be passed in the same way that variables can. If, for some reason, you want to/need to pass a *string*, use normal single/double quotes, not backticks:

```
var timer = setInterval('changeLights()',3000); // but this is bad form
```

If you want to delve into this a bit deeper, try something like this:

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log('foo is invoked');
};
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo))
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === Function.prototype)
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)))
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)) === Object.prototype)
```

This demonstrates that, like arrays or any object, a function just is a specific kind of object with its own prototype. That's why they're first class.

Comment: the second does not work, because you need parenthesis for a stringed value. it is the same evaluation as with `eval`.

Comment: @NinaScholz fair enough, added them back again.... I never use the string syntax :)

Answer (score 2):

Strings delimited with backtick characters are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and are newly introduced in ES2015. They aren't universally supported, in particular: No version of Internet Explorer will support them.

Presumably you are using IE (or an old version of another browser) that does not support template literals.

You *could* (but shouldn't) use a regular string literal:

```
var timer = setInterval("changeLights()",3000);
```

… but passing a string is `eval` by another name. It is slow. It can do weird things with scope. It can be hard to debug.

See [the mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

> ```
> var intervalID = scope.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
> var intervalID = scope.setInterval(code, delay);
> ```
>
> **func**
>  A function to be executed every delay milliseconds.
>
> **code**
>  An optional syntax allows you to include a string instead of a function, which is compiled and executed every delay
>   milliseconds. This syntax is not recommended for the same reasons that
>   make using eval() a security risk.

Pass a function instead:

```
var timer = setInterval(changeLights,3000);
```

Comment: I totally agree, I just want to add, if the author will want to pass arguments to the function that gets invoked, then it needs to be wrapped in an anonymous function, so I'd either add an example for that, or just mention it.

Comment: @Alex — They don't (and it doesn't, you can use `bind` instead, which is often better as it avoids closures which can be confusing)

Comment: @Alex the params will be already passed to arguments of function also https://jsfiddle.net/zws1h9p2/1/ even without any explicit bind()

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible, or hard to pass arguments to a function of this shape. I was just saying that it might be worth it to take the asker's level of language understanding into account when formulating an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is that you have a `changeLights` function somewhere. If you get the error that the function is not defined, it's because the function defined as a string will be executed in the context of the window. If you have a scope-defined function you should encapsulate your first parameter in a local function that can lexically access your function, like such:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() { changeLights() },3000);
```

Comment: Why wrap `changeLights` in an anonymous function? Why not pass it as an argument directly?

Comment: That's a suggestion, because next time he'll want to pass arguments to the `changeLightStrength(10)` function, and he'll not want to bind 10 to the first argument :)

Answer (score -2):

You will need to change

```
var timer = setInterval(`changeLights()`,3000);
```

to

```
var timer = setInterval('changeLights()',3000);
```

It should be in quotes.

Comment: @Aria - The first one is in backtick and the second one in single quote

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted other than it does not explain that ticks are not supported in all browsers?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal sorry yes, but it is not good form, and how about browsers support.

Comment: @Aria I believe, single quotes work everywhere and backticks don't as of yet.

Comment: @epascarello I guess this is getting downvoted because, even though it works, it's arguably the worst way to solve the problem. JS is, to a large extent, a functional language and should be used as such

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem actually I think it was because of an invalid comment (which was deleted) and the herd of downvoters read the comment and ignored the post.

Answer (score -3):

This isn't how it works. The first argument to `setInterval()` is either

1. : an anonymous function
2. : a reference to a function.

To reference functions you just type their name without brackets, doing this you'd end up with the following code: `var timer = setInterval(changeLights,3000);`

Comment: 1 & 2 are the same thing. It should also accept a string.

Comment: 1 & 2 are not the same thing.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval -- Strings are not recommended.

Comment: A function is a function. It doesn't matter if it is anonymous or not. It will always be a reference to it.

Comment: Except one has a name and the other does not. I was merely explaining that you shouldn't invoke it.

Comment: Also, since you haven't provided a solution your presence is rather pointless.

Comment: May not be recommended but that is not the same as *"This isn't how it works"* which is not accurate

Comment: Fair enough, I'll agree with you.